# Update subset of columns in one dataframe from another if key matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames with identical columns. Column 'key' will have unique values.

Data frame 1:-

```
A B  key C    
0 1  k1  2    
1 2  k2  3    
2 3  k3  5
```

Data frame 2:-

```
A B key C    
4 5 k1  2    
1 2 k2  4
2 3 k4  6
```

I would like to update rows(only for columns A and B, keeping C same) in Dataframe-1 with values in Dataframe -2 if key in Dataframe -2 matches with Dataframe -1. Also if key is new then add entire row from Dataframe-2 to Dataframe-1.

Final Output Dataframe is like this with same columns.

```
A B key C
4 5 k1  2   --> update
1 2 k2  3   --> no changes
2 3 k3  5   --> no changes
2 3 k4  6   --> new row
```

Answer (score 1):

You can align indices and then `combine_first`. Since this method doesn't let you specify columns, you can recover `'C'` values from `df1` in a separate step.

```
# align indices
df1 = df1.set_index('key')
df2 = df2.set_index('key')

# combine dataframes preference to df2
res = df2.combine_first(df1).astype(int)

# recover C values from df1
res['C'].update(df1['C'])

# elevate index to series
res = res.reset_index()

print(res)

  key  A  B  C
0  k1  4  5  2
1  k2  1  2  3
2  k3  2  3  5
3  k4  2  3  6
```